# My question regarding ERDs in Visio was closed as off-topic. The FAQ says otherwise

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

[The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) says that questions covering "software tools commonly used by programmers" are OK, but my question [In Visio 2010, how can I create a mandatory, non-identifying relationship between two database tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630045/in-visio-2010-how-can-i-create-a-mandatory-non-identifying-relationship-betwee) was downvoted and closed as off-topic.

Can anyone tell me what's so wrong with the question that it deserved to be downvoted or closed?

Comment: I think calling Visio a "software tool commonly used by programmers" is a bit of a stretch, don't you think? Also your question wasn't down voted, when a question is closed as off topic it receives an automatic down vote.

Comment: I'm on the fence on this one. Visio is used by some programmers in aid of their task but is not exclusively for programmers and is not strictly speaking a programming tool. I've cast a reopen vote just to get you started, but don't hold your breath on this one.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: What's the difference between being downvoted and receiving a down vote...?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I meant he wasn't down voted by a human...

Comment: @YannisRizos I agree that Visio wouldn't necessarily be on topic, but I thought it would be OK for a problem that is software-related. As I said to Mat though, the community seems to think otherwise, which is fine. Thanks for the info about the auto-downvote, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand this entry of the FAQ:

> software tools commonly used by programmers

in the Stack Overflow context as *programming tools*, i.e. IDEs, compilers, editors, build tools, source control management systems, etc.

I don't see Visio as fitting, unless you're dealing with macros/automation. (Trying to generate code stubs/schema from your diagrams would be on topic from my point of view.)

The question you have is an "end user" question. The question itself (the problem you have getting a particular shape/diagram symbol) is hardly programming related. The fact that an ERD is involved doesn't quite cut it, in my opinion.

That said, your question is clear, well written and presented, and I believe in scope for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com). You could ask for it to be migrated there.

Comment: I'm a programmmer and I use Visio to document complex dependencies between programs and jobs. That makes it a tool used by programmers, even though it is not a programming tool. :-)

Comment: I'm not saying Visio isn't commonly used by programmers. I'm saying the question asked would be better on a site that deals with questions about using software. IE, Chrome, Firefox are also used commonly, but questions about using those, "end-user" questions, are off-topic on SO. (IMO, as always.)

Comment: Fair enough. I thought that Visio would be ok (as long as it was for some programming-related topic), but the consensus seems to be against me on this one. How do I ask for a migration? Should I just flag it and ask in the comment thingy?

Comment: Yes, a flag ("other" reason) would be the way. Ask for migration to SU; you can include a link to this discussion if you want, that will give more context to whoever handles it (who might decide to re-open it on Stack Overflow :) - you're in a bit of a gray area).